# If $f$ is entire and $\lim_\limits{z\to\infty} e^{f(z)} = 4$, show that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

I've solved similar problems and the basic idea is to first prove that $f$ is bounded, meaning we need an inequality of the form $|f(z)|<M$. In some problems the relevant inequality is already given while in others you need to modify the given relation to form it by yourself.

The second and final step is to prove that $f'(z)=0$ by using Cauchy's Integral formula along with the bounding inequality.

In this problem I'm having trouble with the first step.  I'm using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of the limit which gives:
$$\forall{\varepsilon} > 0, \exists{n_0} \in \mathbb{N} : \forall{\left|z\right|} \geq n_0:|e^{f(z)}-4|<\epsilon$$

Now, how do I isolate $|f(z)|$ to get the bounding inequality ?

Comment: Can you see that $e^f$ is a bounded entire functions, and therefore constant?

Comment: What do you mean by entire function

Comment: @parthsachdeva holomorphic in $\mathbb C$

Comment: Then isn't this question wrong f(x) can be $ln4-e^{-x}$

Comment: Do you mean limit as $\|z\|\to\infty$?

Comment: @AlvinL The problem writes $z\to \infty $. I'm not sure if they meant to write $\|z\|\to\infty$.

Comment: @parthsachdeva It's the limit as $z\to\infty$ in the complex plane. In the complex variable $$\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=L\Leftrightarrow \forall\varepsilon>0,\exists M>0,\forall z,(\sqrt{z\overline z}\ge M\Rightarrow \sqrt{(f(z)-L)\overline{(f(z)-L)}}<\varepsilon)$$

Comment: yeah, the same as $\|z\|\to \infty$, then since $z\overline{z} = \|z\|^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $e^f$ is a bounded entire function. Hence it is a constant function, by Liouville's theorem. As the limit of $e^f$ is $4$ as $z\to\infty$, we in turn obtain $e^{f(z)}=4$ for every $z\in\mathbb C$. Therefore, for each $z$, we must have $f(z)=\log 4+2k\pi i$ for some integer $k$ that may possibly depend on $z$. However, since $f$ is continuous, $k$ must remain constant thoughtout $\mathbb C$. Hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $e^f$ is a bounded entire function? I mean, how do we deduce that from the limit given?

Comment: @JohnKatsantas $e^f$ is the composition of two entire functions $\exp$ and $f$. Hence it is entire. As $e^{f(z)}\to4$ as $z\to\infty$, there exists a closed disc $D$ centered at $0$ such that $|e^{f(z)}-4|<1$ when $z\not\in D$. Hence $e^f$ is bounded outside $D$. As $D$ is compact, $e^f$ is also bounded on $D$. Hence $f$ is bounded on the whole complex plane.